# image hidden after position absolute in react native

Tags: react-native, styling

I have view and image like this.

```
<View style={styles.popularImageViewContainer}>
     <Image style={styles.popularImageStyle} source={{uri: //imgURI }} />
</View>

<View style={styles.currentUserImageContainerStyle}>
     <Image style={styles.currentUserImageStyle} source={{uri://imgURI }} />
</View>
```

This is the style  I am adding in them.

```
currentUserImageContainerStyle:{
    minHeight:24,
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom:0,
    right:0
},
currentUserImageStyle: {
    height: 24,
    width: 24,
    borderRadius: 100,
}
```

But, the image of the style "currentUserImageStyle" remains hidden in the bottom. I can see the image when I click it, but I cannot see the image normally. I cannot find anything like z-index in React Native, any help I can get using position absolute and still see the image?

EDITED: 
Here is the popularImage style above which I want my userImage..

```
  popularImageStyle: {
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
    borderRadius: 10,

  },
  popularImageViewContainer:{
    elevation: 3,
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#000',
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the problem caused by the `.popularImageStyle` image or other elements in your DOM? Your ordering of Views dictates that the `.currentUserImageStyle` should be shown on top of the other image, so the problem might be caused from somewhere else.

According to the documentation, there is a [zIndex](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props#zindex) prop that can be used but there is a better way of achieving the z-ordering you desire, and yet quite simple: just move the userImage `View` to be **after** all the other elements that should precede it – elements displayed later in the hirarchy have priority over the earlier ones, as it can be seen in this Snack: https://snack.expo.io/@siavas/stackoverflow-53970973

Should the above solution not be relevant to you (depending on your overall hierarchy), just add the zIndex prop to your `styles.currentUserImageContainerStyle` and it will behave in the same way you would expect in CSS:

```
currentUserImageContainerStyle:{
    minHeight:24,
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom:0,
    right:0,
    zIndex: 1,
}
```

---

Comment: @JustABeginner if the image contained in `.popularImageViewContainer` needs to be on top of the other, put the zIndex declaration in there then: 
`popularImageViewContainer { elevation: 3,
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#000',
    zIndex: 1,
}`. Firstly I would try swapping the two Views if that is applicable to you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually , z-index is determined by you in the render() function.
The order in wich you put your components determines z index.
Since you are using absolute position try this

```
<View style={styles.currentUserImageContainerStyle}>
           <Image style={styles.currentUserImageStyle} source={{uri://imgURI }} />
    </View>
<View style={styles.popularImageViewContainer}>
          <Image style={styles.popularImageStyle} source={{uri: //imgURI }} />
        </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ther may be something that´s messing things up in your component, or in your render() function. try deleting things to see where the image starts to show up.
It's working, https://snack.expo.io/rJrojU8-N i made a simple snack showing that what you are trying is working as it should be. So the problem is not there